# multiple (dynamic) calls of RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

I want to fetch multiple datasets data in a single React component.

When there is only one dataset, it's simple by using the following `RTK query`.

```
const { 
    data: deviceRecord, 
} = useDeviceRecordListQuery({ deviceId: ID, ... }, {
    selectFromResult: result => ({
        ...result,
        data: result.data?.map((res) => ({
            x: res.x,
            y: res.y,
        }))
    }),
    skip: !chartData 
})
```

But when there are multiple datasets data, I am not sure how to achieve that with `RTK query` as the **number of datasets fetched changes dynamically**. The dataset fetched is determined by `ID` like this and comes as a prop from parent component

```
const data = [
    {ID: 1},
    {ID: 2},
    ...
]
```

I was thinking using the `RTK query` call in a loop somehow, but because the rules for hooks, I can't.

It is not important, but the result of my effort should be a single Line chart (ChartJS library) with multiple data lines.

**EDIT:**
Here is the api slice:

```
import { citywebApi } from "../../openapi/citywebApi"
import { processError } from "../../utils/errors"

export const devicesImportChartsApiSlice = citywebApi.enhanceEndpoints({
    addTagTypes: ['devicesImport'],
    endpoints: {

        deviceRecordList: {
            async onQueryStarted(_, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
                try {
                    await queryFulfilled                    
                } catch(error) {
                    processError(error, dispatch, 'err msg')
                }
            },
            providesTags: ['devicesImport']
        },
        
    }
})

export const {
    useDeviceRecordListQuery
} = devicesImportChartsApiSlice
```

and here is a part of the api auto generated file:

```
import { emptySplitApi as api } from "./emptyApi";
const injectedRtkApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
...
    deviceRecordList: build.query<
      DeviceRecordListApiResponse,
      DeviceRecordListApiArg
    >({
      query: (queryArg) => ({
        url: `/api/device_record/list/device_id/${queryArg.deviceId}`,
      }),
    }),
...
  }),
  overrideExisting: false,
});
export { injectedRtkApi as citywebApi };
...
export type DeviceRecord = {
  device_id: number;
  unit_type: string;
  time_utc: string;
  value: number;
};
export type DeviceRecords = DeviceRecord[];
export type DeviceRecordListApiResponse = DeviceRecords;
export type DeviceRecordListApiArg = {
  deviceId: number;
  ...
};
```

the result data should be array (representing chart) containing arrays (representing each dataset/line in the chart) and the objects are Cartesian values for that dataset:

```
[[{x:1697656739, y:10},{x:1697657739, y:15},...],[{x:1697656739, y:5},{x:1697657739, y:1},...],...]
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] that includes all the relevant code you are working with. In this case, the API slice and the `chartRecordList` endpoint, and an example of the result data you need back in the UI.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for comment. I have added the requested, but not sure, if that is all you were asking for. Basically I am not solving error, just looking for a way how to do a multiple requests to a single useQuery while hooks in a loops are forbidden

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest updating the `deviceRecordList` endpoint to consume an *array* of device ids and use a `queryFn` function to enqueue multiple backend requests, consolidating the responses into a single array.

See [Performing Multiple Requests with a Single Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#performing-multiple-requests-with-a-single-query) for more details.

An example implementation may look similar to the following:

```js
import { emptySplitApi as api } from "./emptyApi";

export type DeviceRecord = {
  device_id: number;
  unit_type: string;
  time_utc: string;
  value: number;
};
export type DeviceRecords = DeviceRecord[];
...

const injectedRtkApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    ...
    deviceRecordList: build.query<DeviceRecords, number[]>({
      queryFn: async (arg, api, extraOptions, baseQuery) => {
        const requests = arg.map(id => baseQuery({
          url: `/api/device_record/list/device_id/${id}`,
        }));

        const results = await Promise.all(requests);

        // results is an array of DeviceRecord[], flatten
        // to single DeviceRecord[]
        return results.flat();
      },
    }),
    ...
  }),
  overrideExisting: false,
});

export { injectedRtkApi as citywebApi };

...
```

Update the query call to pass in the array of device ids.

```js
const { 
  data: deviceRecord, 
} = useDeviceRecordListQuery(data.map(({ ID }) => ID), {
  selectFromResult: result => ({
    ...result,
    data: result.data?.map(({ x, y }) => ({ x, y }))
  }),
  skip: !chartData 
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for that solution inside the query. At the end we found an in-component solution with useEffect feeding the parameters of the useDeviceRecordListQuery. There was an issue with rerender loop caused by "selectFromResult", but it was solved by removing it and moving the map inside the useEffect.